# failure to compile a C program

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, chromium, clion

I am trying to compile a very simple ("hello world!" like) C program with Clion, but I am keep failing.

this is my code:

```
 #include "main.h"
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main() {
 printf("hi hi hi\n");
 return 0;
 }
```

main.h:

```
 #ifndef EXONE_HELLO_H
 #define EXONE_HELLO_H

 #endif //EXONE_HELLO_H
```

nd my make file:

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
 project(exone)

 set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ­-Wextra ­-Wall ­-Wvla​ -­std=c99")

 set(SOURCE_FILES main.c main.h)
 add_executable(exone ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

but I get this message:

```
/dist/local/x86_64.debian64-5776/jetbrains/clion-1.1/bin/cmake/bin/cmake

--build /tmp/.clion-oarzi/system/cmake/generated/48ee084e/48ee084e/Debug      
--target exone -- -j 4

[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/exone.dir/main.c.o 
cc: error: -Wextra: No such file or directory 
cc: error: -­Wall: No such file or directory 
cc: error: ­-Wvla​: No such file or directory 
cc: error: -std=c99: No such file or directory
CMakeFiles/exone.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target
'CMakeFiles/exone.dir/main.c.o' failed make[3]: ***
[CMakeFiles/exone.dir/main.c.o] Error 1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67:
recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/exone.dir/all' failed make[2]: ***
[CMakeFiles/exone.dir/all] Error 2 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for
target 'CMakeFiles/exone.dir/rule' failed make[1]: ***
[CMakeFiles/exone.dir/rule] Error 2 Makefile:118: recipe for target
'exone' failed make: *** [exone] Error 2
```

also, this happen when I just compile with gcc using the console, and when I
change `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` everything works fine (even if I
change only in the first of two places).

Update:
It appears I used minus signs instead of dashes. now I get only one CC error:

> ```
> `cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wvla​’`
> ```

Comment: It is trying to invoke the `cc` compiler which is not installed/cannot be found on your platform. Not really programming-related..

Comment: Huh. @EugeneSh. of course it is. See the site FAQ.

Comment: if i just try "gcc main.c" it works.

Comment: read again about [cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/), do you see now the difference?

Comment: no. 'CMAKE_C_FLAGS' or CXX doesn't appear there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your variable `SOURCE_FILES` you don't need the header file, because it will be found by the compiler. You also need the qoutes for it to work.

```
set(SOURCE_FILES "main.c")
add_executable(exone "${SOURCE_FILES}")
```

Also you need to set the compiler options with a dash infront for all compiler options (you missed the one for `-Wextra`)

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wextra -Wall -Wvla -std=c99")
```

Now your CMakeLists.txt should look like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(exone)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wextra -Wall -Wvla -std=c99")

set(SOURCE_FILES "main.c")
add_executable(exone "${SOURCE_FILES}")
```